# New Item form field validation in SharePoint

Tags: validation

I have created a custom list with below two columns.
1. Choice with Yes/No values
2. Multiple lines of text

In New Item form of this list, on click of save button I want to make field 2 mandatory only when "Yes" is checked in field 1.
Please let me know how can i achieve this and please excuse me for such a novice question, I am really very new in sharepoint.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An event  Receiver would indeed a possible solution here.You'd then override the ItemAdding event checking the Checkbox field value if yes and textbox is empty then cancle event firing and return false.
Something like this:

```
  properties.Cancel = true;
  properties.ErrorMessage = "Item Must Required";
  properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithError;
```

Let me know if u done with this.

Comment: I am sorry but i am very new in Sharepoint and I also have been told that custome coding not allowed so i am really not able to follow your answer. :(

Comment: Ok according to you are able to use javascript then see this solution
http://ghamson.wordpress.com/2011/01/25/useful-javascript-function-presaveaction-sp2010-sharepoint-ps2010-projectserver-in/

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010customization/thread/0c77954e-596a-4e66-aa6b-2f066449f338

Answer (score 2):

In list settings you can only set, that field is either required or not.

To do some more advanced logic, you probably would need to create [Custom Field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms434697.aspx), and write your own validation based on values from another field.

Use of Event Receivers is of course another way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you please provide some more information? Right now i am using PreSaveAction() function and in this function i am taking handle of the fields by id, took id from the web page source. also let me know if it is not a good way of doing this..

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately multiple lines of text fields are not allowed in formulars.

If you can change Field2 to a single line of text then you can add a validation saying `=OR(NOT(Field1),Field2>"")`